# How to disable clickonce Hash Validation

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am deploying an app using click once where I would like to disable hash validation of the assemblies included. Is there a way to do this from visual studio or do I need another tool to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0, you can remove the hashing by going to the Signing tab and unchecking the box that says "Sign the ClickOnce manifests".

Note that you shouldn't do this if you are publishing to the internet. There will be no verification of the files to make sure they haven't been tampered with when the user installs or updates their application.

Answer (score 23):

Please note that this is about hashing - not signing!

Yes, there are two ways to do this:

1. Manually: simply remove the hash-XML-elements within the .manifest file. Note that if you modify the .manifest-File, the hash of that .manifest-file also gets different. So the hash-XML-Element regarding the .manifest-file needs to be removed within the .application file, where it references the .manifest.
2. Visual Studio: On the publish tab, click on "application files...". The right column says "Hash(include)". Just set the files to "exclude", if you want to change them afterwards.

Official documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/che5h906.aspx

Comment: Any way to cancel it globally from the project rather than by checking each file in the list?